# Java generic parameter itself using generics?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to figure out how to structure a program using Java's generics, and wondering if I am doing something fundamentally wrong or just missing a simple bug in my code.

Say I have a generic class:

```
public interface Handler<T>{ 
 public void process(T t); 
}
```

Another generic class takes Handler as a generic parameter (pseudo code):

```
public interface Processor<S extends Handler<T>>{ //<== Error: cannot find symbol 'T'
 public void addHandler(S u); 
 public void process(T t);
}
```

Abstract implementation providing boiler-plate implementations

```
public abstract class ProcessorImpl<.....> implements Processor<.....>{
  ...
}
```

Think of a processor as an object that dispatches requests to process data to any number of handlers.  Specific instances can be variations of process pipelines, intercepting filters, event systems, etc.

I'd like to be able to use it like the following:

```
Handler<String> myHandler1 = new HandlerImpl<String>();
Handler<String> myHandler2 = new HandlerImpl<String>();
Handler<Integer> myHandler3 = new HandlerImpl<Integer>();

Processor<Handler<String>> proc = ProcessorImpl<Handler<String>>();
proc.addHandler(myHandler1);
proc.addhandler(myHandler2);
proc.addhandler(myHandler3);//this should be an error!
```

I can't get it to work.  On paper it looks like it should be trivial, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you say '//error!'.  Do you mean you would like it to be an error?  Or that the compiler is issuing an error that you want to avoid?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  The "//error!" on the last line is expected.  I want that to the an error.

Comment: Great.  Then my answer below is actually relevant to the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So each type parameter is only defined within the class, thus `T` isn't defined or available in `Processor` class.

You probably want to have `Processor` be:

```
public interface Processor<T>{
  public void addHandler(Handler<? super T> u); 
  public void process(T t);
}
```

Here you are declaring a `Processor` that can only handle events/input of a particular type, e.g. `String`, `Integer`, etc.  So the following statement will be valid:

```
Processor<String> proc = ...
proc.addHandler(new Handler<String>());   // valid
proc.addHandler(new Handler<Object>());   // valid, as Strings are Objects too
proc.addHandler(new Handler<Integer>());  // invalid, not a String handler
proc.process("good");     // valid
proc.process(1);          // invalid, not a String
```

If `Processor` is intended to handle types at runtime and makes a dynamic dispatch based on the appropriate runtime type, then you can declare `proc` (in the last example) as `Processor<?>`.  Then all the statements are valid.

Comment: Why not 
`public void addHandler(Handler<T> u);`

Comment: @Harold, this works too, yet it's a bit restrictive.  Having `addHandler` accept `Handler<T>` prevents `Processor<String>` from accepting `Handler<Object>`, and this should be valid.  Imagine a `LoggerHandler<Object>` that simply prints the argument.  You should be able to pass it to any processor I think.

Answer (score 1):

These changes should work:

```
public interface Processor<T, S extends Handler<T>>
```

and

```
class ProcessorImpl<T, S extends Handler<T>>
    implements Processor<T, S>
```

and

```
Processor<String, Handler<String>> proc = new ProcessorImpl<String, Handler<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't work, as your T=String and handlers of integers are not allowed.
At compile time, your class will have method process(String t) and not process(Integer t).